Spring 5.3 app on Tomcat 9.0 throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
I am trying to get a Spring application running on Tomcat 9. When i start the tomcat with the application i get following error message:
Error deploying deployment descriptor [Servers\Tomcat v9.0 Server-config\catalina_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\app-web.xml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:132)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
...
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app-web]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:687)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4817)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
    ... 56 more

Any suggestions how i can resolve it or move forward?
Spring Version 5.3; Tomcat 9
I am not so experienced with Tomcat so i don´t know really where to start.

If your application is missing ApplicationContext that means whatever you deployed to your tomcat did not include any of the Spring Jars.
